# Mongoose: Model.remove callback arguments differ

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) `waterfall` method in my application and I need to specify the arguments in every callback function.

```
async.waterfall([
    function (next) {
        Client.remove({ store: store }, next);
    },
    function (objectsRemoved, next) {
        Item.remove({ store: store }, next);
    },
    function (objectsRemoved, next) {
        Store.remove({ _id: store.id }, next);
    },
// ...
```

The code above works fine in the server, but fails in my local environment. This is because the callback arguments for mongoose's `Model.remove` differ on both sides.

In the server I get `function (err, objectsRemoved)`

Locally I get `function (err, objectsRemoved, anotherObject)`

The weird thing is that in both cases I'm running the same version of mongodb (2.4.9) and mongoose (3.8.20).

Any idea of what could be happening?